# framed editing Ckeditor disabled

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I did what's in the documentation, I have the file linked:

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Then the textarea and script:

```
<textarea name='editor1' class="form_textarea" ><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

The value of $description is not showing in the editor, and the whole editor is disabled. I can't click on any buttons or type anything. I read that this can happen with inline editing, but this is framed.

Comment: Can you echo `$description` outside of editor? Is it fine? Does it bring a correct HTML markup?

Comment: Before installing Ckeditor I was using just the textarea to edit the content, everything was good. Just tried to echo it outside, it's fine.

Comment: Show us a full output of the variable, please.

Comment: It's just that random Lorem Ipsum text at the moment, but whatever I write in there instead of the variable, it doesn't show up.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when using the 'customized' CKEditor. Same code worked fine with the 'Standard Package'.

Comment: I just tried with a different 'customized' package with a much smaller set of plugins and it works. I suspect that one of the plugins is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, that was it. It's a huge pain to get a working customized editor.